# Webbrowser opens two windows instead of two tabs

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-webbrowser

I'm trying to open two websites in two tabs in my web browser. What actually happens is that two separate web browser windows are opened.

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new('https://www.msn.com')
webbrowser.open_new_tab('https://www.aol.com/')
```

Comment: the `webbrowser` module is dependent on your default browser - what browser are you using?

Comment: @DerteTrdelnik
You can define which browser you want to use. See code below (suitable for default chrome path in windows):

ChromePath = 'C:/Program Files(x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'

webbrowser.get(ChromePath).open_new_tab('AOL.com')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely that browser hasn't finished opening by the time you ask for a new tab. The docs do state that if no browser is open open_new_tab() acts as open_new(), which is why you are seeing two browsers.

I suggest putting a small delay between the calls:

```
import webbrowser
import time
webbrowser.open_new(url1)
time.sleep(1)
webbrowser.open_new_tab(url2)
```

Your other option is to poll the running processes and wait until the first instance of the browser appears before asking for a new tab.

Comment: Works with 5 seconds delay for Internet Explorer.